# For Cycle in Array comparing to prior element in For Cycle

Tags: java

I am writting an application and am making a method getMaxHeight

It takes n and an array as an input and then tries to figure out what the maxium height is.

It is calculating cube heights if they would be stacked ontop of eachother and they wouldn't have a bottom face.

I.E.
https://pasteboard.co/HWyCD4m.png

My current code is this

```
static int getMaxHeight(int n, Box[] arr) 
  {

        Box []boxes = new Box[n];

        for(int i = 0;i<n;i++) 
        {
            Box curr = arr[i];
            boxes[i] = new Box(curr.height);
        }

        int maxHeight = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            if(i == 0) {
                maxHeight = arr[i].height;
            }

            else if (maxHeight < arr[i].height && arr[i].height > arr[i-1].height) {
            maxHeight = arr[i].height;
            }
        else if(maxHeight >= arr[i].height && arr[i].height > arr[i-1].height) {
            maxHeight = maxHeight;

        }
        else if(maxHeight > arr[i].height && arr[i].height < arr[i-1].height) {
            maxHeight = maxHeight + arr[i].height;

        }
            }return maxHeight;

}
```

The first if makes it set the starting box the maximum height.

The second if checks if the maxHeight is smaller than the boxes height, if it is and the boxes height is also bigger than the box before it is the new maxHeight (3rd option in the image above)

The third if checks to see if the box is both smaller than the max height and if it's bigger than the previous box (2nd option in the image)

The third one checks if it's both smaller than the max height and smaller than the previous box
(1st option in image)

How do I make this faster? This seems to be too slow

Comment: Why are you creating a new array of Box objects instead of using the one given as an argument?

Comment: @YuvalG cause it didn't work if i used the one given as an argument, I don't know why, this is real spaghetti code

Comment: @YuvalG also, it threw me a NullPointException and the only way I fixed it was by using a new array, again, i have no idea why

Comment: Please add some further explanation as to what you intend your method to do.

Comment: @YuvalG  I hope I rewrote the question better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be what you're trying to do:

```
static int getMaxHeight(int n, Box[] arr) {
        int maxHeight = arr[0].height; // set max to be the first box
        Box previous = arr[0];
        for (int i = 1; i < arr.length; i++) {
            int curHeight = arr[i].height;
            if (curHeight > Math.max(previous.height, maxHeight)) {
                maxHeight = curHeight;
            }
            else if (curHeight < Math.min(previous.height, maxHeight)) {
                maxHeight = maxHeight + curHeight;
            }
            previous = arr[i];
        }
        return maxHeight;
    }
```

I removed one of the `if` statements since the statement `maxHeight = maxHeight;` has no practical meaning.
Let me know if this works.

Comment: thanks man! that does the exact same thing as my code but is both faster, prettier and nicer! I do appreciate the help!

Comment: Glad to help! Note that this will still throw a NullPointer Exception if your Box array is empty. This can easily be solved by checking that `arr.length > 0` at the beginning of the method and returning null or some default value as necessary

Comment: Yeah, do you think it's better to have that check in the function itself or when asking for the input variables? I had the check when I asked int n through a scanner, if it wasn't a natural number then I threw a System.error(0), would there be a difference between having the check down there or in the function?

Comment: No, there wouldn't be a difference as far as functionality. When you define a method, you're essentially defining a contract that should be followed by anyone who uses it. In this regard, if it makes sense for you that this method will only be used for non-empty arrays, that's completely fine. I would do this check when asking for input, and if the array is left empty I would print a helpful message with usage instructions.

Answer (score 0):

You may use the following loop using Math.max (and inititalizing max to Double.NEGATIVE_INFINITY

```
double max = Double.NEGATIVE_INFINITY;
double previous = Double.NEGATIVE_INFINITY;
for(int i=0; i<array.length; i++)
{
  double current = array[i];
  if(current < previous) {
    max = max + current; // putting on top
  }
  else {
    max = Math.max(max, current); // max
  }
  previous = current;
}
```

You can do the if-else in one line, if you like

```
max = current < previous ? max + current : Math.max(max,current);
```

or

```
max = Math.max(max,current) + (current < previous ? current : 0);
```

Comment: okay, yeah, but uhm that doesn't sort the issue out if the box is bigger than the previous one, but not bigger than the current maxiumum height ( I added an image to make my quesiton more understandable) so I don't really know if this is aplicable here, cause I have no clue on how to implement that then.

Comment: I believe it does. The first case in your image is the if() {} part. The second and third case are the else {} part, because max stays max if current is smaller and max becomes current if max is bigger. Thats what Math.max does. - Or maybe I did not understand the problem right.

Comment: i messed up on how i tried testing it out, this option also works really nice, thank you, but i'm really new to programming in general and this just confused me at the start of how to make this a working function, appreciate the help!